# MySQL says Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a form and it is suppose to pass three variables onto my database. I not able to submit my variables to the database, it gives me this error:

```
"Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES) in /home/simples2/public_html/insert.php on line 2

Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'username'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/simples2/public_html/insert.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/simples2/public_html/insert.php on line 15
Error:"
```

I am not sure what needs to be done here. I have checked for spellings, passwords and syntax to my best of abilities which is quite less but I am not able to do.

Comment: Make sure to snip out sensitive information such as IP addresses and absolute paths/usernames!

Comment: Did you recently create the user `simples2_form` user on the database If so, did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after adding it?

Comment: Thanks @msanford rookie mistake :)!

Comment: I did Flush privileges, I might try using localhost, thanks a tone for the reply!

Comment: Localhost worked, this is new Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Tank) VALUES ('22/07/13','40','40')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would verify that the MYSQL database user allows that username allows connections from that ip address.  It seems that the user account was setup for 'username'@localhost or the password is incorrect

Comment: Localhost worked, this is new Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Tank) VALUES ('22/07/13','40','40')' at line 1